# XNA: I only have 1 supported display mode (800x600)

Tags: graphics, xna, adapter, resolution

I'm trying to get my game to automatically set the window size as the correct resolution for the monitor.
For example, my desktop PC is at 1920x1080 resolution, so I want my game to run at 1920x1080 on here, however my laptop is at 1366x768 so I want my game to run at 1366x768 on there, etc.

I've tried so many different things such as GraphicsDevice.Adapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width/Height, and even printed out the list of GraphicsDevice.Adapter.SupportedDisplayModes and they all tell me that the only display mode supported for me is 800x600. This is surely not the case, because I'm running my Windows 7 at 1920x1080.

So what on earth am I doing wrong? I tried putting this code in the Game1 constructor, the initialiser, I can't figure out why it isn't working properly!

Comment: Have you tried:

`mGraphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = mGraphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
mGraphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = mGraphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;
mGraphics.IsFullScreen = true;`

Comment: What's mGraphics? That's not a variable I have declared. I'm assuming it's the same as "graphics", i.e. the GraphicsDeviceManager object. In which case, I've tried that but I am still told that the DisplayMode Width and Height are 800x600

Comment: Correct. mGraphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this); Are you running in fullscreen? Also just to confirm, you are doing all this in the Constructor of your Game object, right? Not sure if it would work after that point (as the window would already be created).

Comment: I'm not running in fullscreen.. Because even if I do graphics.IsFullScreen = true; OR graphics.ToggleFullscreen();, it doesn't do anything?! Yes, this is in the Game1 constructor.. I've also tried putting it in the Initialize and Update methods just to see if there's a difference, but STILL nothing makes a difference! My game is adamant that my GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode is 800x600

Comment: Also, just to add what I forgot, when I tried the code you suggested, I got an error at mGraphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = mGraphics.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width --- a NullReferenceException

Comment: That NullReferenceException sounds odd. Are you creating your GraphicsDevice? (eg. graphics = new GraphicsDevice(this);)? Maybe posting your Game1 class would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. I just realised I was being a little bit stupid in that I forgot to mention this a "MonoGame" application, not a straight forward XNA project... (I didn't think it would make a difference but oh I was wrong)..

As it turns out, MonoGame has a massive bug to do with the graphics devices, and there is supposedly a way to solve it (build from the latest source or something?) but what I did was install the XNA 4.0 Refresh for Visual Studio 2013, and copied all my source code across to a new XNA project as opposed to a MonoGame project.

And hey presto, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width and Height are now correctly registering as 1920 and 1080 pixels. So now I can carry on with my game FINALLY.

Thanks to all the people that tried to help me solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the resolution of your game in the constructor by adjusting the graphics' PreferredBackBufferWidth and PreferredBackBufferHeight:

For example this will produce a game window that's 480x320:

```
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 320;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480;

    }
```

Keep in mind that when in windowed mode your game will (by default) have a title bar which prevents the game window from being as big as your full screen.

Comment: That's not the OP's question!

Comment: I interpreted the question to be - "I can't set my game's resolution to my monitor's resolution", in that the OP knew the monitor's resolution but not how to apply that value to the game.

Comment: you need to Apply the settings. graphics.Apply() or somthing iirc.

Answer (score 0):

This is my method on how to get your maximum supported resolution(and set it, as an example to clarify it):

```
// in the Initialize method
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;
graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
graphics.ApplyChanges(); // <-- not needed in the Game constructor
```

However, I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I just tried that exact code in the initialize method but it still only sets to 800x600.. If I add a couple of breakpoints in and hover the mouse over GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width and Height, it tells me that those two figures are indeed 800 and 600.
Is there something obvious that I'm missing? The default resolution of my PC and monitor are 1920x1080

Comment: @SY6Dave You aren't missing anything.
I have no idea.
I once had a weird bug in my code that it had the wrong values too, without any reason. I didn't really research it further, but what I bassically did was do this code in the `Update` function when a key was pressed (as a toggle). Maybe you could try to do this code one time in the `Update` function? Try that.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm going to set up an XNA project on my laptop and see if the resolution will set right on there, and if so I guess I'll transfer the project across and finish it on there.. If not, I'll just add in a bunch of different resolution options like you said that can be toggled

Comment: @SY6Dave Good idea(both of them), but that's not what I meant. I mean cloning the code above and run them in the update method once. That fixed my weird bug.

Comment: I tried that, making it so that it runs the code when you hit enter... Same problem - seems to think the DisplayMode.Width and Height are 800 and 600!